# I want a button beneath my datatable to show up if I have only 1 record. How can I pass the ID of the record in table when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, c#, button, asp.net-core-mvc, parameter-passing

Here is the chtml code for the table with my buttons where I want them.  I also included the javascript for the table and my .cs controller for the Drawing button.  The controller works if I put a button in the table row and pass the record Id on click but I don't want the button in the row. This is because the button intentionally only becomes visible when the datatable is filtered down to one remaining record.

```
<br />
<div class="container row p-0 m-0">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h2 class="text-info">Device List</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 border p-3">
        <table id="DT_load" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Drawing File</th>
                    <th>Barcode</th>
                    <th>Date Modified</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>

    </div >
    <div class="row" >
        <a asp-action="Drawing" class="btn-primary" id="btn1" style="width: 100px" value="0">
            View Drawing
        </a>
        <a asp-action="Location" class="btn-primary" id="btn2" style="width: 100px">
            View Location
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});


function loadDataTable()
{
    dataTable = $('#DT_load').DataTable
    ({
        "ajax":
        {
            "url": "/devices/getall/",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns":
        [
            { "data": "dwgfilename", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "barcode", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "moddate", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "locationdwg", "width": "20%" },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data)
                {
                    return `<div class="text-center">
                        /*ignore*/
                        </div>`;
                }, "width": "60%"
            }
        ],

        'infoCallback': function (settings, start, end, max, total, pre)
            {
                if (total == 1)
                {    
                    $("#btn1").show();
                    $("#btn2").show();
                    return 'Showing your record';
                }
                else 
                {
                    $("#btn1").hide();
                    $("#btn2").hide();
                    return 'Showing ' + total + ' of ' + max + ' records';
                }
            },

        "width": "100%"
    });
}
```

here is the controller for the button

```
public IActionResult Drawing(int id)
        {
            //draw
            Device = _db.Devices.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
            if (Device == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var filename = Device.Dwgfilename;
                var stream = new FileStream(@"c:\users\boxworks\documents\" + filename +".pdf", FileMode.Open);
                return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the below working demo and make modification on your javascript:

```
function loadDataTable() {
        dataTable = $('#DT_load').DataTable
            ({
                "ajax":
                {
                    "url": "/home/getall/",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json",
                    "dataSrc":""
                },
                "columns":
                    [
                        { "data": "orderNumber" },
                        { "data": "orderDate" },
                        { "data": "description" },
                        {
                            "data": "orderId",
                            "render": function (data) {
                                return `<lable hidden>`+data+'</lable>';
                            }, "width": "60%"
                        }
                    ],

                'infoCallback': function (settings, start, end, max, total, pre) {
                    if (total == 1) {
                        var id = $("#DT_load tbody tr").find("lable").text();

                        $("#btn1").attr("href",$("#btn1").attr("href") + "?id=" + id);
                        $("#btn1").show();
                        $("#btn2").show();
                        return 'Showing your record';
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#btn1").hide();
                        $("#btn2").hide();
                        return 'Showing ' + total + ' of ' + max + ' records';
                    }
                },

                "width": "100%"
            });
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Okay you are amazing.  Thank you soo much!  How did you figure this out?  What should I have googled in order to not have to resort to asking questions on forums?  BTW it only works for me right now in debugging mode and if I put a break point in the infoCallback.  I think it is moving ahead before the id is read in from the database so it's sending null to the IActionResult. I need to figure this out but you have moved me light years ahead.  Thanks again!

Comment: If my workaround works , could you mark my reply as answer? This will help other people who face the same or similar issue to find the issue quickly. You could post a new thread for the new issue.